# ¿Es posible al enviar un FORM, generar un CSV y mandarlo a una carpeta?

Tags: php, jquery, formularios, csv

llevo ya unas horas investigando, y no he conseguido encontrar mucha información útil.

Con lo que me remito aquí a ver si puedo encontrar ayuda.

- Tengo un formulario, que lo trabajo con jQuery, con lo que ahí tengo almacenadas todas las variables y datos.
- Quiero intentar hacer lo siguiente: al enviar el formulario, generar un archivo CSV que se guarde en una carpeta cualquiera del servidor. Con un formato concreto.

*¨No tengo nada hecho, ya que he intentado indagar y no he encontrado mucha información.

Agradecería ayuda para saber si podría hacer esto en PHP y jQuery.

**EDICIÓN DE LO QUE HE INTENTADO**

He creado un archivo PHP:

```
<?php
    $cod_cliente = ($_POST['cod_cliente']);
    $optica = ($_POST['optica']);
    $fecha = ($_POST['fecha']);
    $tipo = ($_POST['tipo']);

    $lista = array (
        array('Codigo Cliente', 'Cliente', 'Fecha', 'Tipo'),
        array('$cod_cliente', '$optica', '$fecha', '$tipo'),
    );

    $fp = fopen('fichero.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($lista as $campos) {
        fputcsv($fp, $campos);
    }

    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Y dentro del jQuery de enviar el pedido, este ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/generarCsv.php',
    data: {'cod_cliente': cod_cliente,
           'optica': optica,
           'fecha': fecha,
           'tipo': tipoCi}
  })
  .done(function(listas_rep){
    alert('CSV Generado con exito');
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('Error al crear el archivo CSV')
  })
```

He de decir, que arriba de ese ajax, tengo otro, el cuál me envía a la base de datos el pedido. Nose si hará conflicto.

Esto, ahora mismo, no me hace absolutamente nada.

Comment: Si es posible ¿El fichero hay que generarlo cuando se recibe el formulario en el servidor o de forma asincrona cuando se envia?

Comment: De forma asíncrona cuando se envía el formulario, ahora mismo solo lo tengo enviando a la bbdd

Comment: Vale, vas a tener que crear un archivo php que reciba los datos (ya sea por POST o por GET) y este los grabe al fichero. Para grabar en formato csv -> http://php.net/manual/es/function.fputcsv.php. Luego cuando envies el formulario tienes que capturar el evento y hacer una llamada ajax con jQuery al archivo php que creaste -> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Genial! Voy a echar un ojo al manual de fputcsv, y te digo!! Gracias!!!!

Comment: @JDev He editado mi pregunta, con la intención de enseñarte lo que he intentado hacer, algo con lo que no he conseguido absolutamente nada. No me hace nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes que entrecomillar las variables de la segunda fila. El siguiente código sí debiera funcionar:

```
<?php
$cod_cliente = 'ejemplo cod_cliente';
$optica      = 'ejemplo optica';
$fecha       = 'ejemplo fecha';
$tipo        = 'ejemplo tipo';

$lista = [
    ['Codigo Cliente', 'Cliente', 'Fecha', 'Tipo'],
    [$cod_cliente, $optica, $fecha, $tipo],
];

$fp = fopen('fichero.csv', 'w');

foreach ($lista as $campos) {
    fputcsv($fp, $campos);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Me extraña que digas que no escribe nada, porque a mí me funciona perfecto. Si quitando las comillas igual no se genera un archivo csv puede ser por otro problema como:

- Que la carpeta no tenga permiso de escritura para el usuario que ejecuta php (e.g. `www-data`)
- Que el archivo exista y no tenga permiso de escritura
- Que una de las entradas de la superglobal `$_POST` no se esté recibiendo.

En este último caso, debieras comprobar la existencia de la variable, por ejemplo haciendo:

```
$cod_cliente = isset($_POST['cod_cliente'])? $_POST['cod_cliente'] : 'no especificado' ;
```

Comment: Listo!!! Si que es cierto que funciona! el problema eran las '$variasbles' entre comillas.. ¿Si añadiera esto? ¿Me crearía un archivo por cada pedido? $fp = fopen('fichero'.$cod_cliente.'.csv', 'w');

Comment: Sí, aunque si vas a trabajar con user inputs, vas a tener que preocuparte de que no ingresen datos que ensucien tus archivos. Campos cambiados por ejemplo: ingresan un código donde va el nombre del cliente y viceversa. Un CSV no tiene validación de datos. ¿Quieres un archivo por cliente o que se vayan añadiendo filas al csv del mismo cliente? ¿No has pensado mejor usar una BBDD?

Comment: Hola Amenadiel, ya lo tengo solucionado, ya importo cada pedido a una base de datos, pero también necesitaba sacar un archivo CSV por pedido, ya que se envía automáticamente via FTP al fabricante en este formato :)